# input fields values undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to send values from HTML form to javascript file but I saw that **the values for email subject and message were sent as undefined in alert window or console**, while the name was correctly fetched from input and transferred to js,I am quite new to javascript so this question might be very silly but I am unable to figure out the reason why undefined is sent and also I don't understand that when in what order the javascript and HTML code is executed, I Sometimes see the javascript is being executed first before the button is clicked 
heres my html form stored in **temp.html**

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Contact Form</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">

      </head>
      <body>

        <form id="connect-form" method="POST">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="card-body col-lg-6 col-sm-12  col-md-6">
                                    <div class="md-form mt-3">
                                        <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" required="required">
                                        <label for="materialContactFormName">Name</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="md-form mb-3" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" id="name" required="required">
                                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="md-form mb-3" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" id="name" required="required">
                                        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                                    </div>        
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body col-lg-6 mt-2 col-sm-12 col-md-6">  
                                    <div class="md-form">    
                                        <textarea class="form-control md-textarea" name="message" rows="4" id="message" 
                                         placeholder="say Hi, and I will probably get back to you in 24 hrs :)" style="resize: none; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; height: 100%;" required="required"></textarea>
                                        <label for="message">Message</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>      
                            </div> 
                            <div class="form-action" style="text-align: center;margin: auto" >
                                    <button onclick="contactuser()" class="btn btn-elegant btn-block" type="submit" style="height: 50px;width: 50%;" >Submit</button>
                                </div>
                          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/file.js"></script>                        
                        </form> 
                </div>

                <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
            <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
            <!-- MDB CORE JAVASCRIPT -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
            <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

file.js located in js folder

```
  function contactuser(){
var Name = document.getElementById("name").value; 
var Email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
alert("Button Clicked" + "Name: " + Name + "Email:" +Email + " subject:"+ subject);
}
```

output image  that I get

https://ibb.co/dfjBUU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID in html are unice you can't use id="name" for 3 inputs.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Contact Form</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <form id="connect-form" method="POST">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card-body col-lg-6 col-sm-12  col-md-6">
                <div class="md-form mt-3">
                    <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" required="required">
                    <label for="materialContactFormName">Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="md-form mb-3">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control mb-3" id="email" required="required">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                </div>
                <div class="md-form mb-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required="required">
                    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body col-lg-6 mt-2 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="md-form">
                    <textarea class="form-control md-textarea" name="message" rows="4" id="message" placeholder="say Hi, and I will probably get back to you in 24 hrs :)" style="resize: none; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; height: 100%;" required="required"></textarea>
                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-action" style="text-align: center;margin: auto">
            <button onclick="contactuser()" class="btn btn-elegant btn-block" type="submit" style="height: 50px;width: 50%;">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/file.js"></script>
    </form>
</body>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB CORE JAVASCRIPT -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and js its ok

```
    function contactuser(){
var Name = document.getElementById("name").value; 
var Email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
alert("Button Clicked" + "Name: " + Name + "Email:" +Email + " subject:"+ subject);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to give the attribute id to the input element not for the div

```js
function contactuser(){
var Name = document.getElementById("name").value; 
var Email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
alert("Button Clicked" + "Name: " + Name + "Email:" + Email + " subject:"+ subject);
}
```

```html
<form id="connect-form" method="POST">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="card-body col-lg-6 col-sm-12  col-md-6">
                                    <div class="md-form mt-3">
                                        <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" required="required">
                                        <label for="materialContactFormName">Name</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="md-form mb-3" placeholder="Email">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" id="email"  required="required">
                                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="md-form mb-3"  placeholder="Subject">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" id="subject" required="required">
                                        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                                    </div>        
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body col-lg-6 mt-2 col-sm-12 col-md-6">  
                                    <div class="md-form">    
                                        <textarea class="form-control md-textarea" name="message" rows="4" id="message" 
                                         placeholder="say Hi, and I will probably get back to you in 24 hrs :)" style="resize: none; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; height: 100%;" required="required"></textarea>
                                        <label for="message">Message</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>      
                            </div> 
                            <div class="form-action" style="text-align: center;margin: auto" >
                                    <button onclick="contactuser()" class="btn btn-elegant btn-block" type="submit" style="height: 50px;width: 50%;" >Submit</button>
                                </div>
                          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/file.js"></script>                        
                        </form> 
                </div>
```